# Prevent Keyboard from appearing when tapping on UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextfield

I'm using a **UITextField** to show results of a calculation but I **don't** want the keyboard to appear when the user taps on the **UITextField**.

I'm using a UITextField because I still want the user to be able to Copy and Paste the calculation back into the UITextField, but I don't want the keyboard to show up.

**UIKeyboardWillHide** only works after the keyboard is displayed.

Comment: You can use UITextView with editing mode as disabled.

Comment: I use **textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false** but then the Copy and Paste also no longer works.

Comment: If you disable the userInteraction means you cannot detect the taps on the UITextField. As suggested use UITextView with editing mode as disabled.

Comment: In Swift 3 I don't see **UITextField.enabled** = false ?

Comment: Not UITextField, Use UITextView with code: textView.isEditable = false

Comment: That works but dynamic text size doesn't with UITextView. I wouldn't have thought there will be such a difference in using UITextView instead of UITextField but that is iOS for ya!

Comment: iOS is never so rude that you need to change your control for some simple requirement. Please check my answer

Answer (score 12):

Swift 4.2, This works for me.
put in `viewDidLoad()`

```
//It will Hide Keyboard
textField.inputView = UIView()
//It will Hide Keyboard tool bar
textField.inputAccessoryView = UIView()
//It will Hide the cursor
textField.tintColor = .white
```

Comment: For iPads, see this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64678330/7486818)

Answer (score 8):

Its quite simple to do with UITextField. Use this code in **`viewDidLoad()`**

```
self.txtresult.inputView = UIView()
  self.txtresult.inputAccessoryView = UIView()
```

Answer (score 5):

For iPads, according to this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59066191/7486818) of [@Awais Jamil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9321469/awais-jamil), add the following code

```
textField.inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups = []
textField.inputAssistantItem.trailingBarButtonGroups = []
```

Comment: If I may ask? Where are these located in SwiftUI

Answer (score 3):

First set `delegate` with your `UITextField` in `self` class.

You can do with below 2 ways. 
1. From storyboard 
2. From Code ( You can write at `viewDidLoad()` ) 
`textField.delegate = self`

Then declare protocol `UITextFieldDelegate` in your class.

Now call delegate method.

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
textField.inputView = UIView()
```

This line of code in your textFieldDidBeginEditing func will do the job.

My func:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        keyboardView.activeTextField = textField
        textField.inputView = UIView()
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can hide keyboard in `UITextFieldDelegate` method `textFieldDidBeginEditing:(textField: UITextField)`  like below :

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing:(textField: UITextField) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use an "empty" inputview like this:

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let inputView = UIView(frame: .zero)
    inputView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    inputView.opaque = false
    textField.inputView = inputView

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well VIA text field delegate method.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        // your custom impl
}
```