# Swiftui - Disable Keyboard from showing up for TextField

Tags: swiftui, keyboard, textfield, disable

For swiftui are there anything for disable/prevent keyboard from showing up for TextField?

because I am designing a calculator and getting the input from the design instead of keyboard

Comment: Just use `Text`, if you don't want user input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UITextField` with `UIViewRepresentable`, which lets you stop the keyboard from showing up.

```
import SwiftUI

struct KeyboardView: View {
    @State var text: String = ""
    @State var placHolder: String = "Enter username"
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            MyTextField(currentText: $text, placeHolder: $placHolder)
                .padding(.horizontal, 40.0)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct MyTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var currentText: String
    @Binding var placeHolder: String
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.inputView = UIView() // hiding keyboard
        textField.inputAccessoryView = UIView() // hiding keyboard toolbar
        textField.placeholder = placeHolder
        textField.textColor = UIColor.black
        textField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22.0)
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        return textField
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ textField: UITextField, context: Context) {
        textField.text = currentText
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(text: $currentText)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        @Binding var text: String
        init(text: Binding<String>) {
            self._text = text
        }
    }
}
```

Reference: [Prevent Keyboard from appearing when tapping on UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45560653/prevent-keyboard-from-appearing-when-tapping-on-uitextfield)

Answer (score 1):

if you already have a `TextField` setup, you can add `.disabled(true)`,
this will stop the keyboard from showing up.

```
TextField("", text: $txt)
   .disabled(true)  // <--- here
```

Comment: Thanks. Fixed the default keyboard popping up when using a custom keyboard.